# ¿Por que me imprime las dos lineas de codigo?

Tags: java

los pongo en contexto estoy haciendo un menu de opciones por consola pero al momento de pedir datos se imprime las dos lines de codigo.

```
 Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre;
        int cantidad;
        Tienda t = new Tienda();
        System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion: ");
        System.out.println("    1. Vender producto. \n"
                + "    2. Hacer pedido de producto. \n"
                + "    3. Producto mas vendido. \n"
                + "    4. Producto mas vendido. \n"
                + "    5. Promedio de ventas. \n"
                + "    6. Salir. ");

        switch (entrada.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("¿Que producto desea comprar?");
                System.out.println(set);
                nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("¿Cantidad que desea llevar?");
                cantidad = entrada.nextInt();
                t.venderProducto(nombre, cantidad);
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
        }

    }
```

al momento de desplegar el menu va todo bien elijo la opcion (1 - vender producto) al elegir se imprime de seguido lo siguente

¿Que producto desea comprar?
[]
¿Cantidad que desea llevar?

como lo puedo solucionar ? gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te quedaria asi, el nextLine antes de la asignacion del nombre para que puedas avanzar hasta la proxima linea:

```
            System.out.println("¿Que producto desea comprar?");
            System.out.println(set);
            entrada.nextLine();
            nombre = entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.println("¿Cantidad que desea llevar?");
            cantidad = entrada.nextInt();
```

Mis resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]